# Is there any free plugin for eclipse that helps managing layouts

Tags: eclipse-plugin

i just look the last version of netbeans (6.7.1). desktop applications almost like .net

[alt text http://www.bearfruit.org/files/netbeans-gui-builder.png](http://www.bearfruit.org/files/netbeans-gui-builder.png)

very easy to design...

Is there any **free** eclipse-plugin which helps on managing designs like netbeans...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hope on the "free eclipse plugin" department is the revival of **[Eclipse Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/)**.

It is to [be installed](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Update) on a eclipse Galileo 3.5 with p2 manager (the provisioning mechanism)

[image]
<sub>(source: [canoo.com](http://www.canoo.com/ulc/images/fullscreenshot.gif))</sub>

The [ULC Visual Editor](http://www.canoo.com/ulc/external/ve-releasenotes.html) product is already built upon it for its drag-and-drop GUI designer for UltraLightClient to develop rich user interfaces for Java EE applications.
([UltraLightClient](http://www.canoo.com/ulc/products/canooulc.html) being a library to build Rich Internet Applications end-to-end in Java.)